# Inherit multiple Django choices classes in one choices class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, enums

Let's say we have two `choices` classes in Django like:

```py
from django.db import models


class C1(models.TextChoices):
    attr1 = "ATTR1", "Attr 1"
    attr2 = "ATTR2", "Attr 2"


class C2(models.TextChoices):
    attr3 = "ATTR3", "Attr 3"
    attr4 = "ATTR4", "Attr 4"
```

And we need to inherit these two classes in one choices class like this:

```py
class C(C1, C2):
    pass
```

It throws an error like this: `TypeError: C: cannot extend enumeration 'C1'`

Answer (score 2):

After extensive research, looks like django `Choices` uses `enum` behind the scenes, and the `enum` [class can not be inherited](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-enum-subclassing).

But it is possible to aggregate multiple `Choices` classes to yield one class having all the fields of aggregated `Choices` classes.

```py
fields_dict = {item.name: item for item in (*C1, *C2)}
C = models.TextChoices("C", fields_dict)
```

But this will not preserve the name, choice and label of `Choice` field. So, we can do something like this to achieve this.

```py
fields_dict = {
    item_name: item_choice
    for item_name, item_choice
    in zip(
        (*C1.names, *C2.names),
        (*C1.choices, *C2.choices)
    )
}
C = models.TextChoices("C", fields_dict)
```

---

I prepared this generic function to include as many classes we want.

```py
def generate_aggregated_text_choice_class(
        class_name: str, *choices_classes: models.TextChoices
):
    fields_choices = [choices for _class in choices_classes for choices in _class.choices]
    fields_names = [choices for _class in choices_classes for choices in _class.names]

    fields_dict = {
        item_name: item_choice
        for item_name, item_choice
        in zip(fields_names, fields_choices)
    }

    return models.TextChoices(class_name, fields_dict)


C = generate_aggregated_text_choice_class("C", C1, C2)
```